# Htaccess - 301 domain redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my old domain to the new one. Actually my site is under www_olddomain_pl/index.php and english version under www_olddomain_com/index_en.php

What I want to do?

```
olddomain_pl -> www_new_pl
www_olddomain_pl -> www_new_pl
odldomain_com -> www_new_com
www_olddomain_com -> www_new_com
```

And redirect from index to without index.
What I actually have?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)olddomain_pl(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www_olddomain_pl/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www_new_pl/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)olddomain_com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www_new_com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't know what to do.

EDIT:
**One more:**
Actually I've two version of my site - polish and english.
Polish version is under olddomain_pl/index.php
English version is under olddomain_pl/index_en.php

I want have:
Polish version under new_pl
English version under new_com

So I need redirect from without www to with www and from index.php or index_en.php to without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index_en\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.live-dent.com/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} live-dent\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.livedent.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** As per comment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} live-dent\.com\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.livedent.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work...
If I write: olddomain_pl/something in otput I'vewww_olddomain/somethingsomething
Something is wrong.

One more:
Actually I've two version of my site - polish and english.
Polish version is under olddomain_pl/index.php
English version is under olddomain_pl/index_en.php

I want have:
Polish version under new_pl
English version under new_com

So I need redirect from whitout www to whit www and from index.php or index_en.php to whithout that.

Comment: Your english version is under `www.olddomain.com/index_en.php` OR `www.olddomain.pl/index_en.php`?

Comment: English version is under www.olddomain.com/index_en.php AND www.olddomain.pl/index_en.php. Look - www.live-dent.pl

Comment: Ok in that case my suggested rule will work. Make sure above rule is 1st rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` and you test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: And (the last question, I promise) if I want to redirect live-dent.pl/index.php (www and without www) to www.livedent.pl, but live-dent.pl/index_en.php and live-dent.com/index_en.php (with and without www) to www.live-dent.com (with dash)?

Comment: I checked this rule in htaccess.madewithlove.be/
It's perfectly redirected (www)live-dent.pl to www.livedent.pl.
But it doesn't work for live-dent.com because this redirected this url to www.livedent.com.
I don't want to do that. I want to redirect (www)live-dent.pl/index.php to www.livedent.pl but (www)live-dent.pl/index_en.php and (www)live-dent.com/index_en.php to www.live**-**dent.com (with dash).

Comment: Alright made edit again, try it now. Also don't use `htaccess.madewithlove.be` for testing, it is not very reliable. Test it on your own server.

Comment: You're amazing! That works, but only webmaster have access to server and he can change .htaccess tommorow. Thank You very much!

Comment: Hi @anubhava! Can You help me to modify the code which You wrote yesterday? I need only to add a redirect from (www)live-dent.com.pl to www.livedent.pl

Comment: Are You shure this rule correctly redirects from live-dent.com to www.live-dent.com?

Comment: But you commented: `(www)live-dent.com.pl to www.livedent.pl`

Comment: You're right: (www)live-dent.com.pl to www.livedent.pl, but (www)live-dent.com to www.live-dent.com.

Comment: You're right: (www)live-dent.com.pl to www.livedent.pl, but (www)live-dent.com to www.live-dent.com.
To sum up:
- (www.)live-dent.pl -> www.livedent.pl
- (www.)live-dent.com.pl -> www.livedent.pl
- livedent.pl -> www.livedent.pl
- live-dent.com -> www.live-dent.com
- index.php (file on server) = polish version
- index_en.php (file on server) = english version

Is it possible to redirect from *.php to without php too? For example:
- from www.live-dent.pl/stomatologia-estetyczna-i-zachowawcza.php to www.livedent.pl/stomatologia-estetyczna-i-zachowawcza/

The task becomes much more difficult :)

Comment: If it gets too complicated I request opening a new question with all scenarios described in question so that all can be addressed properly.

Comment: I created new question. It is avalible under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571054/advanced-htaccess-301-domain-redirection