# Advanced htaccess - 301 domain redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my old domain to the new one. I've two version of my site - polish and english. Domains that I have are: live-dent.pl, live-dent.com, live-dent.com.pl and livedent.pl.
I want to redirect:

- (www.)live-dent.pl/index.php, (www.)live-dent.com/index.php, (www.)live-dent.com.pl/index.php and livedent.pl/index.php to
  www.livedent.pl (**without dash**),
- (www.)live-dent.pl/index_en.php, (www.)live-dent.com/index_en.php, (www.)live-dent.com.pl/index_en.php and livedent.pl/index_en.php to
  www.live-dent.com (**with dash**).

To this I want to redirect 404 error to a custom page. Path to polish version of this file is:

- www.livedent.pl/404.php, and
- www.live-dent.com/404_en.php for english version (this file does not exist now).

The code that I've now (thanks to @anubhava) is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index_en\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.live-dent.com/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} live-dent\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.livedent.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The rule ErrorDocument 404 /404.php doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all these domains share the same document root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?live-dent\.(pl|com|com\.pl)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HIST} ^livedent\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php
RewriteRule ^ http://www.livedent.pl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?live-dent\.(pl|com|com\.pl)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HIST} ^livedent\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index_en\.php
RewriteRule ^ http://www.live-dent.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank You very much! Do you know why the rule: ErrorDocument 404 /404.php doesn't work?

Comment: @user2911046 do you have other rules?

Comment: No, I don't. Now I have:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index_en\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.live-dent.com/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} live-dent\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.livedent.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

I don't have access to the server now, so this is the old code. Are You sure that the last line will be working properly with Your version of code?